# Python NameError: global name 'inv' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7

I am making an automated script for one of the popular MMORPG out there. I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    startFishing()
  File "C:\Python27\DG\RS\RS bot.py", line 56, in startFishing
    if inv == "full":
NameError: global name 'inv' is not defined
```

I have detailed my functions below.

```
def isMyInventoryFull():
    s = screenGrab()
    a = s.getpixel((1173,591))
    b = s.getpixel((1222,591))
    c = s.getpixel((1271,591))
    d = s.getpixel((1320,591))
    if a == b == c == d:
        print "Inventory is full! Time to go back home."
        inv = "full"
        print inv
    else:
        print "Inventory is not full."
        inv = "notfull"
        time.sleep(3)

def startFishing():
    mousePos((530,427))
    leftClick()
    time.sleep(0)
    inv = 'full'
    openUpInventory()
    isMyInventoryFull()
    if inv == "full":
        time.sleep(0.01)
    else:
        isMyInventoryFull()
    mousePos((844,420))
    rightClick()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The thing is, I have defined 'inv' during my 'isMyInventoryFull' function, however it is not picking up that 'inv' has already been defined? I am definitely missing something here, can anyone help?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Paste your code in the box, then highlight it and click `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name inv is currently defined only within the scope of `isMyInventoryFull`, and it will cease existing once the function returns.

I suggest that you return the value of the variable `inv` from `isMyInventoryFull`:

```
def isMyInventoryFull():
    # determine the value of inv
    return inv
```

Then, `startFishing`can get the value of inv:

```
def startFishing():
    # ...
    inv = isMyInventoryFull()
    # now you can use inv
```

Answer (score 0):

Either define your inv variable outside the function, or as a global variable, I think that will solve your problem.